# Sitecore Url works with any Extension

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In my website , the url's are working even entering something after .aspx and giving staus code 200.

Eg: below is normal page with .aspx and status code 200.[image]

But even i have any random extension i got 200 status code which suppossed to be a 404 Status code, 
[image]

Any Help.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore is quite generous when it resolves URL's. If you want to enforce correct extensions, you could create a custom `Item Resolver` which ensures the context item remains null in the `process` method if the URL has the incorrect extension.

Here's a helpful article on creating an Item Resolver:

[Thoughts on httpRequestBegin - Custom Item Lookups](http://insitecore.tumblr.com/post/37848690556/thoughts-on-httprequestbegin-custom-item-lookups)

In my example below, the base process method is called. After that we check if the Context Item meets the requirements, and set it to null if not. (You'll need to implement `TemplateIsAPageType` and `ExtensionIsValid` as you see fit.)

```cs
public class CustomItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor 
{
    public override void Process( HttpRequestArgs args ) 
    {
        base.Process(args);

        if( Context.Item != null && TemplateIsAPageType() && !ExtensionIsValid()) 
        {
            Context.Item = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Another approach might be something like this, where we compare the requested URL with the resolved item's 'ideal' URL:

```cs
public class CustomItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor 
{
    public override void Process( HttpRequestArgs args ) 
    {
        base.Process(args);

        if( Context.Item == null) 
            return;

        var requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        var idealUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Context.Item);

        if(requestUrl != idealUrl)
            Context.Item = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one did you try? If you tried the second example, what are the values of `requestUrl` and `idealUrl` when you debug?

Comment: Page redirects to 404 , but status code is not changing

Comment: OK, then the answer can be found here: http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/11/return-404-status-code-when-itemnotfound-page-is-loaded

Comment: That solution works for me. Essentially the problem is that Sitecore does a 302 to the `NotFound` item and then has a 200 status. The simplest solution would be to add a some code to your specified 404 page that sets the status code to 404.

Comment: +1 Great idea comparing the requested url to the idealUrl. One thing, you probably want to use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` rather than `Request.RawUrl` which would include any parameters too

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore skips everything after the last dot ”.” in an url when attempting to resolve an item. 
This is done by the class Sitecore.Web.RequestUrl which has a property called ItemPath. 
This property attempts to create a valid path to an item from the requested url. It is not possible to override this property.
If you for some reason would like Sitecore to return a 404 status code if an item is requested with a file extension, such as .aspx, you could do something like this in a 404 not found item resolver.
 See this post http://laubplusco.net/handling-404-sitecore-avoid-302-redirects/ the following method extends the one shown in the post.

```
protected virtual bool IsValidContextItemResolved(string filePath)
{
  if (Context.Item == null || !Context.Item.HasContextLanguage())
    return false;
  if (filePath.Contains(".") && !RequestIsForPhysicalFile(filePath))
    return false;
  return !(Context.Item.Visualization.Layout == null 
    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebUtil.GetQueryString("sc_layout")));
}
```

It is important to ensure that the requested url is not for a physical file first. 
This is done by checking that the args.Url.filepath does not map to a physical file. 
The rule which I show here says that if an item has been resolved and the filepath contains a dot then the requested url should return a 404 and the context item should be the not found item. The code could be extended to check what comes after the dot to see if it is a valid extension.